# Is there a nice way to partially-bind class parameters in Python?

Tags: python, partial-application

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
@memoized
def reversed_matching(matching_cls):

    class ReversedMatching(ReversedSequenceMatching):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(matching_cls, *args, **kwargs)

    return ReversedMatching
```

I want to bind one argument of a class and return the “partial class”. I can't use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) because that can't be used with [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) and [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass) and the like. Is there a nicer way to write this?

Comment: @aran-fey it's not a duplicate.   I'm asking about **partial classes**.

Comment: `functools.partial` can be used with any callable, be it a function or a method or a class or anything else.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Unfortunately, the partial object doesn't respond to `issubclass`, so it's not a good solution.

Comment: Okay, I'll reopen. Please add the `issubclass` requirement to the question though.

Comment: @aran-fey, martijn is right, it's a duplicate of *that* question.

Comment: @Martijn thank you!  You're practically an index of this site :D

Comment: No problem @NeilG :)